# Heroku foreman start command stuck in virtualenv while attempting to run Django project

Tags: python, django, heroku, upload, foreman

I am trying to implement Django Heroku tutorial https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django

`python manage.py runserver` works fine both outside and inside virtualenv

`foreman start` works fine outside virtualenv

`foreman start` inside virtualenv the command either stucks on first line or ends with code 1

```
13:29:08 web.1  | started with pid 4231
13:29:13 web.1  | exited with code 1
13:29:13 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

Upd:

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn cell_modelling_site.wsgi
```

Comment: Does `foreman run run python manage.py runserver` works inside your venv? If yes, you can use this.

Comment: It works, but is it really equivalent to `foreman start`? I have Internal Server Error when I `heroku open` and `heroku logs` do not show anything except that I have 500th http request error. I need some tool to give me more info for the cause.

Comment: Can you provide what's in your `Procfile`?

Comment: sure. `web: gunicorn cell_modelling_site.wsgi`

Answer (score 0):

I had faced slimier issue . And I resolved it by installing gunicorn==0.16.1 using pip. Hope this will resolve your problem too....

Replace existing gunicorn by gunicorn==0.16.1

Comment: I think so. When we install django-toolbelt it will install gunicorn. I think it is because of gunicorn version. But python manage.py runserver works fine.